# Fedora 19: Best way to keep /tmp /var/tmp directories clean

Tags: fedora, tmp

Running on Fedora 19, I realized that my `/tmp` directory is out of space.

Trying to find a solution I got confused.

Most answers state that previous releases of Fedora used tmwatch as cron job, which is not the case in my Fedora 19.

Other ways of accomplishing this might be:

```
rm -rf /tmp*
```

or even

```
find /tmp ...
```

which are commands that are considered "not accurate" in filtering the files which might be currently useful in order to preserve them.

My question is:

Is there a script to keep `/tmp` `/var/tmp` and/or other `*tmp` directories sane?

Comment: Why your `/tmp` is not on `tmpfs`? It will get cleaned each reboot.

Comment: Thanx, this is why tmpwatch is not active in Fedora 19.I enabled tmpfs in fstab and works great. `tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,seclabel 0 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In /etc/fstab:

`tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,seclabel 0 0`

This line will put /tmp on tmpfs as it should have been.